# How can one view messages’ sizes in Microsoft Outlook web interface?

Tags: outlook.com

How can one view messages’ sizes in Microsoft Outlook web interface?

For example, in Microsoft Outlook standalone application, the size of each email is visible:

[image]

I am aware that one may sort the messages by sizes. However it doesn't display the exact size of each message, and instead places the messages into vague brackets ("enormous > 5 MB; huge 1-5 MB").